# Paypal Express Checkout - Different Payees depending on Postcode/ZipCode

Tags: paypal

Is it possible to have PayPal select the payee/recipient for an Express Payment (or any other payment) based on the postcode/zipcode they provide in PayPal itself? Especially if someone is a registered PayPal member already and their postcode is not revealed to the website until PayPal returns control for confirmation.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your question.  If they're already in PayPal providing a zip code then they've already logged in. That would make them the receiver.

Comment: The receiver of the goods but I'm talking about the recipient of the money in this case!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing that would come *close* to this would be Adaptive Payments. With Adaptive Payments, you can have your own logic that ties recipients and zipcodes together, and you can adjust the recipient based on your own logic.

You can see the docs for Adaptive Payments here:
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-payments